# The logic behind a specific step of SUSY variation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, supersymmetry, majorana-fermions

I'm following Neil Lambert's Supersymmetry notes, and there's a step in equation 5.67 which has me stumped. He says he uses the fact that "$C\gamma_\mu$ is symmetric". I don't see how that helps, and I'd really appreciate any advice.

$-\frac{i}{2}(\delta\psi_\alpha(C\gamma_\mu)^{\alpha\beta}\partial^\mu\psi_\beta+
\frac{i}{2}(\partial\psi_\alpha(C\gamma_\mu)^{\alpha\beta}\delta\psi_\beta=
-i(\delta\psi_\alpha)(C\gamma_\mu)^{\alpha\beta}\partial^\mu\psi_\beta$

$C$ is the charge conjugation matrix, $\psi$ is a Majorana spinor.

Comment: He moved the variation term in the 2nd term of the l.h.side leftwards, past the derivative of the spinor, picking up a fermion interchange minus sign.  Transposing the matrix after relabeling the indices  yields a term identical to the first term, to which it adds.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I still don't understand how can he swap the places of the variation part and the derivative part through the matrix. I know the two fields should anticommute, but how can we do it through the matrix?

Comment: The matrix is a (bunch of) number(s). After the transposition, you must relabel everything to get uniform expressions, so the matrices in each term, 1st and 2nd, are the transpose of each other. You might consider deleting your question.

Comment: In other words, $$\frac{i}{2}\partial\psi (C\gamma_\mu) \delta\psi = \frac{i}{2}\partial^{\mu}\psi_\alpha(C\gamma_\mu)^{\alpha\beta}\delta\psi_\beta = \frac{i}{2} (C\gamma_\mu)^{\alpha\beta} \partial^{\mu}\psi_\alpha \delta\psi_\beta = - \frac{i}{2} (C\gamma_\mu)^{\alpha\beta} \delta\psi_\beta \partial^{\mu}\psi_\alpha = - \frac{i}{2} \delta\psi_\beta  (C\gamma_\mu)^{\beta \alpha} \partial^{\mu}\psi_\alpha $$ is similar to the inner product of a vector with the outcome of a matrix acting on a vector, $x^t M y = x^i M_i \, ^j y_j = M_i \, ^j x^i y^j = M_i \, ^j y^j x^i = ..$

Comment: Ah, so I shouldn't think of $(Cγμ)^{αβ}$ as a full matrix, but as the $\alpha \beta $ component of the matrix, and so of course the matrix element will commute with the spinors?

Comment: Yes, and then symmetry of the matrix entries lets you simply switch the $\alpha, \beta$ indices since the matrix is symmetric.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks a million Bolbteppa!